# Populate in rails 4 and heroku (SOLUTIONS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, populate

I am new to rails 4 and I'm trying to do a deploy on heroku, but as I can populate my bd de heroku?

I have this in seed.rb

```
Cliente.create([{nombre: 'Jose',apellido: 'Cabarcas',telefono: '7897987',direccion: 'calle 11', cedula: '10236', referencia: 'andu', telReferencia: '898998'},{nombre: 'Andu',apellido: 'Cabarcas',telefono: '7897987',direccion: 'calle 11', cedula: '10236', referencia: 'andu', telReferencia: '898998'}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`heroku run rake db:seed -a your_app_name_on_heroku` from command line in the project's directory

Comment: friends, thank you. I already did, but even me this printing empty screen data :(

Comment: Type heroku run rails console -a your_app_name and then in console Cliente.all

Comment: If answer was helpful, please, mark it as proper or vote it up.